# Z-index, css3 и другие

Tags: z-index, css

Доброго всем кодинга. Что-то я совсем тупею, возраст, правнуки и прочее и прочее...
Вот заткнулся на простом z-index:
ко(т):

```
<style>
body
{
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#back_ground
{
background: #83bbff;
position:relative;
z-index:999;

}
</style>

<body>
<div id="back_ground">

<center>
<div align="center" style="width:80%; border-left:solid 1px #83bbff; border-right:solid 1px #83bbff; padding-bottom:178px; min-width:888px;">
<div align="center" style="width:888px; border:solid 0px #cccccc;">
таблички, картинки и прочее-прочее...
на этих объектах ставлю **position:relative;** - не помогает.
</div>
</div>
<center>
</div>
```

---

Вопрос:
Почему контейнер #back_ground не перекрывает всех?
ставил у тех, кто в нём (child-объекты) **position:relative;**, но не помогло.

сам прожект [тут](http://development.icar-soft.ru/development-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что ему тут перекрывать, если все данные находятся в нем?
Хотите сделать перекрывающий `div`, так сделайте его отдельно, вне контейнера, в котором у вас всё содержимое лежит,   то есть фактически вы в коробку сложили предметы и хотите, чтобы дно коробки у вас перекрыло их.

Comment: Там потом хотел сделать альфа-прозрачность, градиентную.
Поэтому и хотел вынести его перед всеми.
Хм... про коробку пример хороший.
Спасибо, буду переделывать.